# how to use values from async functions in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use string value  in my code but I am unable to do so. Please help, I am new to flutter.

```dart
// Database (db) is database sqlite
// Dog class has a String field name

Text func() async{
     var dog = await db.firstDog();
     return Text(dog.name);
}
```

The return type `Text` isn't a `Text`, as defined by the method `func.dart(return_of_invalid_type)`.

Comment: These links might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY 
 and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/async

Answer (score 1):

use Future

ForExample

```
Future<Text> func() async{
    String d = await getTest();
    return Text(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisites**

- Do tell us where this function call is placed (eg. in repository or screen layer)

**What you can do**

1. Instead of returning the `Text` as `Widget`, you can just return a `Future<String>`

```dart
Future<String> func() async {
     var dog = await db.firstDog();
     return dog.name;
}
```

2. Assuming that you are utilizing this on your screen or widget class directly, you can do this

```dart
Database db = new Database();
String _dogName;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text(_dogName),
    ),
  );
}
void func() async {
     setState(() async {
         var dog = await db.firstDog();
         _dogName = dog.name;
     });
}
```

Comment: it is in screen layer

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](https://medium.com/@takahirom/how-to-write-flutter-asynchronous-processing-22f845204f30) on medium. You can get a good understanding.
For asynchronous functions you should use `Future` class for returning the values.

```
Future<String> asyncFunc() async {
d = await db.firstDog();
return d.name;
}
```

Then use this string to set the text for a `TextView`